# How to include a file in already included files in php?

Tags: php, html

i have a index page in which i included 2 files . when user click  on link 1 (file one) will be included and when on 2 (file two) will be included in a certain div.

**index.php**

```
 <a href="index.php?page=1">link-1</a>
  <a href="index.php?page=2">link-2</a> 

    <?php
    if($_GET['page']==1)
    {
        include("uploads/home.php");
    }
    else if($_GET['page']==2)
    {
        include("uploads/aboutus.php");
    }
    else{
         include("uploads/home.php");
    }
    ?>
```

now look at this  **home.php** file which include when pressed on link 1

Now problem is occurred. Now in home.php i want to add 2 more links 3,4 in home.php and wanted to include files when user press 3,4 link.

what will i have to written in anchor `href`?. i already try `<a href="home.php?page=">link-3</a>` and its says no file found in directory.

if anybody have any idea please share?

Comment: no sir you didn't get my point. that was just an example actually i want to include files in home.php and home.php file is already included in index.php file when user pressed on link-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to follow :) If I get it right (including files in home.php):

if page = 1, include home.php. Then there is another switch in home.php, which will include further php files?

What about this, just as example: index.php?page=3
index.php:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
if ($page == 1 || $page==3) {
   include('uploads/home.php');
}
```

home.php could look like this:

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page']; 

if ($page == 3) {
    include('uploads/home_link3.php');
}
...
?>
```

A better way would be probably to introduce a second parameter $_GET['section'] or something else.

```
index.php?page=1&section=3
```

Check the $_GET['section'] in home.php and include your files.

Anyway, both suggestions are very ugly for me!

Comment: `|| $page=3)` that is an assignment. It should contain another `=`. Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44849999/1

Comment: $page = $_GET['page'];
if ($page == 1 || $page==3) {
   include('uploads/home.php');
}   in this code you placed  a page 3 link on a index.php. but i want that this page 3 link is on home.php

Comment: and GET the value  3 on the  home.php using $_GET

Comment: what i want is in index.php i just included a page and in that included page i just add another include.and after that what will i written in anchor tag to call the index.php --->include page---->inside included page.

Comment: its a nested include.